# Scala substitute missing argument value

Tags: scala

In Scala, the below method should return `10` if it was called as `val n: Int = getNumber()` and `5` if `i` argument was specified as `val n: Int = getNumber(2)`

```
def getNumber(i: Int = 7): Int = 3 + i
```

How can this be done nicely?

Comment: What's the problem with your solution?  It looks pretty nice to me, and does precisely what you want...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Exactly like the code in your question

```
scala> def getNumber(i: Int = 7): Int = 3 + i
getNumber: (i: Int)Int

scala> getNumber()
res0: Int = 10

scala> getNumber(2)
res1: Int = 5
```